# Publish Code Coverage doesn't work in .NET Core Azure pipeline

Tags: .net-core, nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

**I am trying to add Code Coverage results in an Azure DevOps build for a .NET Core project, but, trying two different approaches based on [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?view=vsts&tabs=designer) on MSDN:**

Currently, after building the solution, I have a dotnet step for test, collecting the Code Coverage and publishing those results. I also tryed disabling this check for publishg, and adding a command line step and a Publish Test Results.

Here the screenshot and yaml for the test step:

[image: Test step]

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Test solution'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Test/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"'
    workingDirectory: ChustaSoft.Common.UnitTest
```

And here the screenshots and yaml for the currently disabled steps:

[image: Command line script]

```
- script: 'dotnet test ChustaSoft.Common.UnitTest --logger trx --collect "Code coverage"'
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
  enabled: false
```

[image: Publish test result step]

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: VSTest
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
  enabled: false
```

With both approaches, I could see Test results, but not the Code Coverage, here is an screenshot of what I am able to see it:

[image: Build summary]
[image: Test results]

Any idea? I am missing something? How can I see the Code Coverage when the build is finished?

Thank you a lot in advance,

***PD: Project is multitarget: .NET Core 2.0, .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET 4.6.1, UnitTest project is a .NET Core MSTest project***

EDIT: Added Test step output:
[image: Test output]

Comment: Try to run the tests with adding first `Visual Studio Test Platform Installer` task then `Visual Studio Test -->>Test assemblies` task. Remove the `Publish Test` and the `Command line` tasks.

Comment: hello! I tried, but the result is the same, I can't see the Code Coverage results

Comment: Can you post here the output from the test task

Comment: yes, of course:

Comment: I can see now the warning regarding the Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk reference version, I will update it in the test project and try again

Comment: Now it's working, the problem was this reference version, please, can you reply this post to vote your answer? thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run the tests with adding first

`Visual Studio Test Platform Installer Task`

then

`Visual Studio Test -->>Test assemblies Task`

Remove the `Publish Test` and the `Command line` Tasks.

Comment: Thank you a lot, in addition to this, I've needed to update the version of Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk, and now it's working as expected. 

Thank you again :)